# Sphinx: runtime error django 1.9

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-sphinx

Currently I'm using Django 1.9 and Django Rest Framework. I'm attempting to use Sphinx and it's autodoc functions, but I'm hitting an error on `make html`. The models.py does not import.

```
myapp/
    manage.py
    index.rst
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
    users/
        models.py
    source/
        modules.rst
        users.rst
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myapp',
    'users',
)
```

and the error I get is:

```
WARNING: /home/sestrella/Devel/leroi-angular/source/customers.rst:10: (WARNING/2) autodoc: failed to import module u'users.models'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 657, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/me/Devel/myapp/users/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
  File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 161, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 112, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
/home/me/Devel/myapp/source/modules.rst:4: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'source/ users'
```

modules.rst

```
myapp
=============

.. toctree::
  :maxdepth: 4

   users
```

and users.rst

```
users
================

Modules
----------

users.models
----------------------

.. automodule:: users.models
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Why does the users.models fail to import? I do use the ContentType model in my users.models as a generic relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is an error fix, or a workaround:

in conf.py, add:

```
import django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings' 
django.setup()
```